# Function problem - Error on else statement

Tags: python

I've been working my way through the *Python for Everybody* book by Charles Severance. I'm stuck on one of the problems, even a worked example online doesn't seem to fully answer the question.

> Exercise 7: Rewrite the grade program from the previous chapter using
> a function called computegrade that takes a score as its parameter and
> returns a grade as a string.
>
> ```
> Score
>
> >= 0.9 A
> >= 0.8 B
> >= 0.7 C
> >= 0.6 D
> <0.6 F
>
>
>
> Enter score: 0.95
>
> A
>
> Enter score: perfect
>
> Bad score
>
> Enter score: 10.0
>
> Bad score
>
> Enter score: 0.75
>
> C
>
> Enter score: 0.5
>
> F
> ```
>
> Run the program repeatedly to test the various different values for
> input.

My code is:

```
def computegrade(score):
    if float(score)>1:
        return 'Bad score'
    elif float(score)>=0.9:
        return 'A'
    elif float(score)>=0.8:
        return 'B'
    elif float(score)>=0.7:
        return 'C'
    elif float(score)>=0.6:
        return 'D'
    elif float(score)<0.6:
        return 'F'
    else:
        return 'Bad score'
```

...which seems to work until I type in "perfect" or any kind of non-numerical input (throws an error). Just wondering why this doesn't work with my `else` statement, when word inputs don't fit other criteria?

Comment: The else is never reached, because the comparison *can't be made* if the input isn't numerical. An error is totally different to the comparison just not being true, read e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html.

Comment: _Use_ that fact that an exception is being raised to detect that something invalid (i.e. non-numerical) has been entered and handle it as desired (via a `try`/`except`).

Answer (score 0):

Like most programming language, `if..elif...else` in python works sequentially, meaning from your function, the line `if float(score)>1:` is executed. Now, once you see the full error you will see that python has pointed you to this line as the error.
In this line, it is trying to convert any non-numeric input into a floating point number, which it cannot. Thus your error.

If you want to fix these kinds of issues you have to use *exception handling*. Meaning, you want to avoid your program to crash when you are not getting required data type. For which `try...catch` comes in handy, as explained here - [exception handling](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/exception-handling), and as some other answers have suggested. Also, there are many other methods, like *[switch case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)*, *[type checking](https://realpython.com/python-type-checking/)* etc.

**Note:**

- considering OP I am putting links for some methods I explained which might be helpful for others too.
- type checking might always not be a good idea, but yes you can solve this problem with type checking `if score.isnumeric()` but this works for only integer value, not float.

Comment: How would type hinting or checking help here?

Comment: _type hinting_: My point of view, someone who wants to interact with the function should at least be aware what the function is expecting as input?
_type checking_: directly print if the input is wrong, or send statement from the else block?

Comment: For this kind of problem, switch-case can also be used. But, I don't think OP is looking for these solutions, right?

Comment: Well if I said it was `def computegrade(score: str) -> str:` would it be clearer why *type* checks aren't going to be helpful?

Comment: And Python doesn't have a switch case, so no.

Comment: No, not present directly. But can be implemented [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Comment: Got your point on type hinting! I will make the necessary changes. @jonrsharpe

Comment: You can use a dictionary to approximate a switch, but how would you do that with floats?

Comment: depends on the use case. like here, you can bin the data into class and apply switch-case.

Answer (score 0):

```
def computegrade(score):
    try:
        score = float(score)
    except ValueError:
        return 'Bad Score'
            
    if score > 1:
        return 'Bad score'
    elif score >= 0.9:
        return 'A'
    elif score >= 0.8:
        return 'B'
    elif score >= 0.7:
        return 'C'
    elif score >= 0.6:
        return 'D'
    elif score < 0.6:
        return 'F'

a = computegrade(input())
print(a)
```